# Performance Issues with Skype for Business SDK [Android]

Tags: android, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Has anyone integrated Skype for business Android SDk's in your applications?

We are getting performance issues. The act of initiating and accepting a call from both sides, and for the call to start, is taking 27-35 seconds consistently, rendering the feature as unusable for our Business App.

I have carried out 10 test runs.

Test is carried out by initiating a call from User 1 to User 2.
On average it took 30-35 secs to complete the call start process on both ends.

Shortest time taken for the test: **27 secs**

Longest time taken for the test: **35 secs**

> Average time for our API's to work: **2-3 secs**
>
> Average time for SFB sdk to start the video process (Anonymous call): **12-13 secs**
>
> Average time for User2 to receive video: **9-10 secs**
>
> Average time for User1 to receive video once User2 receives the video:
>   **7-8 secs**

Comment: i didn't use skype but i use Twilio video, and i had this type of problems and it was a matter of network speed and traffic

Comment: I am on a fast network, 6.8 Mbps as reported by fast.com. i am also using Vidyo for video conferencing and its pretty much faster than SFB. Reason why i am expecting some solution from SFB team.